# Clojure - deftype ignored - unable to resolve classname on tests

Tags: syntax, clojure, deftype

I'm testing `deftype` and `defprotocol` in Clojure, but I'm in a bit of a pickle.

I'm using leiningen. My core file (`src/core.clj`) looks like this:

```
(defprotocol Speaker
  (say [speaker message]))

(deftype Person [name]
  Speaker
  (say [_ message] (str name ": " message)))
```

My test file (`test/core.clj`) looks like this:

```
(deftest people-can-talk
  (is (= "Peter: hello" (say (Person. "Peter") "hello"))))
```

When I execute that test (with `lein test`) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: Person, compiling:(my-project/test/core.clj:2)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6416)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
```

I believe it is telling me that `Person` isn't defined. But it is! If it wasn't, wouldn't Clojure have thrown an error? Is there some obvious syntax error I'm missing?

I'm using clojure 1.3.0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use classes defined by deftype in another package/file, you need to (import) them, or provide the full package name, like `(core.Person. "Peter")` - or whatever the namespace for core.clj is.

Additionally, "lein test" only loads the test files. If you want to refer to anything in another file, you'd need to use or require that file in the test file.

Comment: Hi Joost, I doubt this is the case. The test file starts by including the src file. I didn't include that on my code, since it is automatically generated stuff. Maybe I should have, sorry about that. In any case, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Wait wait. I read your answer again. It is actually an issue with the namespaces. The functions are "automatically handled" but the types are not. It worked with `my_project.core.Person. "Peter":w` . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You suggestion did not resolve the class reference error for me.  But implementing a "factory method" as described below is a work-around:
[another stackoverflow answer on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690784/how-do-you-use-a-type-outside-of-its-own-namespace-in-clojure)