# Why can't I instantiate a defrecord-generated class after use'ing its namespace?

Tags: clojure

I'm relatively new to Clojure and going through the Clojure chapter in *Seven Languages in Seven Weeks*, and I can't figure out why this code from the book isn't working for me. I'm using Leiningen and Clojure version 1.5.1. As far as I can tell after careful checking, I typed the code exactly as it reads in the book.

Here is the code:

```
(ns seven-languages.compass)

(defprotocol Compass
    (direction [c])
    (left [c])
    (right [c]))

(def directions [:north :east :south :west])

(defn turn [base amount]
    (rem (+ base amount) (count directions)))

(defrecord SimpleCompass [bearing]
    Compass
    (direction [_] (directions bearing))
    (left [_] (SimpleCompass. (turn bearing 3)))
    (right [_] (SimpleCompass. (turn bearing 1)))

    Object
    (toString [this] (str "[" (direction this) "]")))
```

I'm running "lein repl" from within the directory ~/clojure/seven-languages (created by running "lein new seven-languages" in ~/clojure). Relative to this directory, my .clj files are in src/seven_languages. So far I've been able to successfully import and use them from the repl by typing `(use 'seven-languages.filenamehere)`.

So, after saving the code I listed above as src/seven_languages/compass.clj, I run this from the REPL:

```
user=> (use 'seven-languages.compass)
nil
```

But then when I try to define an "instance" of the SimpleCompass, typing it exactly like in the book, this happens:

```
user=> (def c (SimpleCompass. 0))

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: SimpleCompass, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:8)
```

I also tried loading the file using `(load-file "src/seven_languages/compass.clj")`, but got the same results. Since the actual loading seemed to work as expected, I wonder if there has been some change in how defprotocol or defrecord works in versions of Clojure subsequent to when *Seven Languages in Seven Weeks* was written. In the introduction to the Clojure chapter, the author writes, "I’m using a prerelease version of Clojure 1.2, and it should be fully ready by the time this book is in your hands."

Can anyone tell why this code isn't working properly? If it's a version issue, how would you update this code for Clojure 1.5.1?

**EDIT:** Aha! I figured it out after finding this:
[Clojure - deftype ignored - unable to resolve classname on tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201933/clojure-deftype-ignored-unable-to-resolve-classname-on-tests)

It's a namespace issue. I'm guessing this is a change since version 1.2 when 7LI7W was written. For whatever reason, while functions in imported files are "automatically handled" so that you can just use them directly, types are not automatically handled. You have to include the full path to the type, and make sure you use the actual path with underscores, not hyphens. I got my code to work by substituting `SimpleCompass` with the full path, `seven_languages.compass.SimpleCompass`:

```
user=> (def c (seven_languages.compass.SimpleCompass. 0))
#'user/c
user=> c
#seven_languages.compass.SimpleCompass{:bearing 0}
user=> (left c)
#seven_languages.compass.SimpleCompass{:bearing 3}
user=> (right c)
#seven_languages.compass.SimpleCompass{:bearing 1}
```

Comment: Instead of answering your own question as an edit, you should answer it as an actual answer, so people can upvote it, comment on it, etc. separately from the question.

Comment: I tried that, but I just joined SO. You aren't allowed to answer your own questions until you have a certain amount of reputation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from always fully qualifying the class name, you can `import` it and use the short name afterwards:

```
(import seven_languages.compass.SimpleCompass)

;; (SimpleCompass. 0) etc. will work now
```

Also, it's worth pointing out that `defrecord` creates to factory functions for you, one positional and one taking a map:

```
(defrecord Foo [x])

(->Foo 1)
;= #user.Foo{:x 1}
(map->Foo {:x 1})
;= #user.Foo{:x 1}
```

These are just regular functions and so will have been pulled in by your `use` call.

Relatedly, `deftype`, as of Clojure 1.5.1, creates the positional factory only.